# UDP Client Thread in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, google-maps, udpclient

I am trying to make a udp client thread in my android application which tracks a device (the server sends its coordinates) and displays them on a map using google maps API.  However, I am very stuck since I am very new to Android development.  I have tested my udp connection not in the android application and it works.  I am just struggling with making a new thread.  When I run the application it says "Unfortunately Maps has stopped".

```
new Coordinates().execute(port); //Port is the port # int
```

I am doing this in onCreate()

And

Thanks!

```
private class Coordinates extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> 
{  
    private LatLng ltnlng = null;
    private boolean valid = false;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
    super.onPreExecute();
    // Shows Progress Bar Dialog and then call doInBackground method

}
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... port) {
        try {
            //  int port         =    5005            ;
              byte[] buffer    =    new byte[2048]  ;
              final StringBuilder notification = new StringBuilder("IN TRY" )       ;
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), notification, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()          ;

              DatagramSocket dsocket      =    new DatagramSocket(null)                       ; 
              InetSocketAddress address   =    new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.170", 5005)   ;
              dsocket.bind(address)    ;
              // Create a packet to receive data into the buffer
              DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

              // Now loop forever, waiting to receive packets and printing them.
              while (true)
              {
                  valid = false;
                  final StringBuilder notification1 = new StringBuilder("RECEIVING.." ) ;
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), notification1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()     ;
                  dsocket.receive(packet)  ;
                  final StringBuilder notification2 = new StringBuilder("RECEIVED" )    ;
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), notification2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()     ;
                  String msg        =    new String(buffer, 0, packet.getLength())      ;
                  String delims     =    "[\\s]+"                                       ;
                  String[] tokens   =     msg.split(delims)                             ;   

                  if(tokens[1].equals("nan") || tokens[2].equals("nan") || tokens[1].equals("0.0") || tokens[2].equals("0.0") )
                  {
                    final StringBuilder notification3 = new StringBuilder("NO COORDINATES AVAILABLE" )      ;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), notification3, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()       ;      
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    valid = true;
                    StringBuilder notification4 = new StringBuilder(tokens[1] + "," + tokens[2] )       ;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), notification4, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()   ;
                    ltnlng = new LatLng(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]),Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]));
                  }
                  publishProgress()                 ;
                  packet.setLength(buffer.length)   ;  
              }
            } 

        catch (Exception e) {
            final StringBuilder notification4 = new StringBuilder("ERROR:" + e.toString() )     ;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), notification4, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()   ;
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...params)
    {
        if(valid == true)
        {
            marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("PipeBomb")
            .snippet("Tracking Device")
            .position(ltnlng) 
                    );
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ltnlng))               ;
            final StringBuilder notification=new StringBuilder("New coords" )       ;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), notification, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()            ;
        }
        else
        {
            final StringBuilder notification3 = new StringBuilder("NO COORDINATES AVAILABLE" )      ;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), notification3, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()       ;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer params) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Maps has finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: I edited the post. But when I run it is crashes once getCoordinates() is called @ChiefTwoPencils

Comment: Please include the stracktrace.